# React component is not rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm new to coding and trying my hand at React.

I'm trying to render a component inside another component, but the nested component is getting ignored. Please let me know where I'm going wrong!

I'm using Visual Studio Code and the template react app generated by 'create-react-app'. App.js is being rendered in index.js. Here's what the code looks like:

**App.js :**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class testComponent extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <testComponent/>
        Lorem ipsum
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

'npm start' only gives me Lorem ipsum. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: instead of `testComponent` use `TestComponent` check answers of duplicate ques for explanation, let me know if have any doubt :)

Comment: Mayank, you're a legend! Thank you. Mods, please close this question!